# find and save in a list XML tags with the same name, Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml

I'm working on a python program in i have parsed my XML file with ElementTree. The xml file contains multiple student records like the one i give here. My problem is that i want to save in a list for each student, every 'name' tag. In every student tag, multiple 'name' children tags can be found (there is no certain number i mean). I tried the following method but i can only get the first 'name' tag. Can anyone help me?

```
<student>
    <id>A100</id>
    <name>John</name>
    <name>Johny</name>
    <dob>11/01/1999</dob>
</student>

tree = ET.parse(filename)
root = tree.getroot()
list1 = root.findall('student')
    for i in list1:
        k = i.find('name').text
        names.append(k)
```

Comment: Where do you initialize the array `names`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will give you a dictionary of names, with the "id" tag used as the key for each student. You can then parse the dictionary as you see fit:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml_string = """<root_records>
<student>
    <id>A100</id>
    <name>John</name>
    <name>Johny</name>
    <dob>11/01/1999</dob>
</student>
<student>
    <id>A140</id>
    <name>Mat</name>
    <name>Matthew</name>
    <dob>01/01/1995</dob>
</student></root_records>"""

tree = ET.fromstring(xml_string)
names = {}

for i in tree.iter("student"):
    student_id = i.find("id").text
    k = [x.text for x in i.findall('name')]
    names[student_id] = k

print(names)
```

**Output:**

```
{'A140': ['Mat', 'Matthew'], 'A100': ['John', 'Johny']}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can just find all the name tags and get the text value using a list comprehension regardless of how many name tags are there.

**data.xml**

```
<data>
    <student>
        <id>A100</id>
        <name>John</name>
        <name>Johny</name>
        <dob>11/01/1999</dob>
    </student>
    <student>
        <id>A100</id>
        <name>Adam</name>
        <name>David</name>
        <dob>11/01/1999</dob>
    </student>
    <student>
        <id>A100</id>
        <name>Barry</name>
        <name>Liam</name>
        <dob>11/01/1999</dob>
    </student>
</data>
```

We can make use of xpath syntax to find all name elements in the tree which have a parent elelment of student. We wrap this in a python list comprehension to capture just the names in a list

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('data.xml')
names = []
seperator = '-----'
students = tree.findall('student')
for student in students:
    student_names = [name.text for name in student.findall('name')]
    names += student_names + [seperator]

#pop the last seperator off the end and print the list
names.pop()
print(names)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
['John', 'Johny', '-----', 'Adam', 'David', '-----', 'Barry', 'Liam']
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but i think you misunderstood. The file has plenty of 'student' tags. So i loop through them and for each one I want the children 'name' tags

Comment: you mean to say if you had 100 student records all with two names each you want a single list which would have 200 names?

Comment: let's assume that the xml file, has 100 student records. We don't know how many names each one has. I want a list with all the names but with a separator after all names. So it would be like ['John', 'Johny','---', 'Adam', '---','David', 'John'], etc

Comment: I have updated my answer, i had figured the first answer would haev given you enough to have progressed with the solution. Updated answer but based on your new comment i will update again

Comment: I have updated again based on your changing requirement. Its always best to put in your question your expected output. let me know if this now does what you expect.

Comment: I can't thank you more my friend!! You are right about the formating of my question but forgive me i am new on stack! Again thank you